# Convert JSONObject to ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using Parse cloud code, I have set the return type of the cloud code as `List<ParseObject>`.

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getObjects", params, new
                FunctionCallback<List<ParseObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            //
                        } else {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

When i query for 5 objects, I can retrieve the ParseObjects, I don't face any problem, but when I query for a lot of objects, I get this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseObject".
```

I have done some research, cloud code happened to return `JSONObject`, but why was I able to retrieve the 5 objects as Parse objects but when it comes to many objects, the type is returned as `JSONObject`?

Comment: What do you mean by "many" objects, how are you requesting them ? Are'nt the 5 objects that you request also many objects. Are you sure that the "many objects" request is not returning a json array. What is the Json parser that you are using ?

Comment: Parse has a maximum of objects it can return. Maybe you are hitting it, and the json returned by Parse is different than just a List of ParseObjects.

Comment: there might be some json in your list item that can't be converted tp parseObject

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I was trying to perform random objects query using cloud code, as "many" I mean retrieving all the records but in a random manner. I only have  16 objects, when I only retrieve 5, I have no error, but when i retrieve result.length (which is 16 of them), I have ClassCastException

Comment: @Aakash I have file, number and string type attributes in my class

Comment: you are getting exception at which line?

Comment: @Aakash first line of my for loop trying to loop tru the retrieved parse objects. The first line is ParseFile photo = (ParseFile) object.get("photo");

Answer (score 0):

Check if your Parse Cloud code is retrieving a JSON or an object.

Check a line like this:

```
res.success(JSON.stringify(results))
```

And change it to:

```
res.success(results)
```